# Looking for incident response data

Tags: intrusion, recovery

Good evening cybersecurity community;

I am looking for a nice data set that comprises some cybersecurity incidents **and describes how these incidents were solved**. Doing such documentation is e.g. mandatory part of the ITIL-framework or of ISO 27001.

I already found a few samples on the internet but was hoping for any of you knowing a good source or some better keywords than I am using at the moment.

As NLP will be part of my researchit does not really matter how well-documented / structured the data set it. It'd just be nice if it would contain a couple of different incidents (the more the better).

Any advice? Cheers

Comment: To get an update on what I found so far: https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/ank4hu/searching_for_a_cyber_security_incident_response/